# Chrome issue : Enable/Disable sorting on columns fails in chrome in GWT

Tags: gwt

I am using CellTable from GWT. When user click on some column header to sort, I would like to disable sorting untill the data is retrieved. For this, I am using following code:

```
private void setHeadersSortable(boolean enable) {
  if (_table.getColumnCount() > 0) {
     if (enable) {
        // enable only columns specified in _sortPropertyByColumn
        Iterator<Column<T, ?>> sortableColsIter = _sortPropertyByColumn.keySet().iterator();
        while (sortableColsIter.hasNext()) {
           sortableColsIter.next().setSortable(enable);
        }
     } else {
        // disable all columns
        for (int i = 0; i < _table.getColumnCount(); i++) {
           _table.getColumn(i).setSortable(enable);
        }
     }
     _table.redrawHeaders();
  }
```

}

This all works fine in Firefox and IE but not in chrome.

It seems that in Chrome, it fails in _table.redrawHeaders(). The call fails in gwt class AbstractHasData which throws IndexOutOfBoundsException

```
protected void checkRowBounds(int row) {
    if (!isRowWithinBounds(row)) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Row index: " + row + ", Row size: " +      getRowCount());
     }
  }

protected boolean isRowWithinBounds(int row) {
     return row >= 0 && row < presenter.getVisibleItemCount();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved by deferring redrawHeaders() call

```
Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new ScheduledCommand() {
        @Override
        public void execute() {
           _table.redrawHeaders();
        }
     });
  }
```